# Convert Json Object to independent columns in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following csv file (converted to Dataframe)

```
asOfDate,name,details                                         |
2022-06-06,Vasanth,{"degree":"BE", "score":72.0, "subject" :"ECE"}
```

And then, using the above file, I need to convert to the following using pandas

```
asOfDate,name,details.degree,details.score,details.subject
2022-06-06,Vasanth,BE,72.0,ECE
```

I tried to use json_normalize, but getting error "str" has no attribute values

Please let me know how to convert into prescribed format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the json field to columns by applying `json.loads` to it, convert the values to a list and then `join` that to the rest of the dataframe, dropping the redundant `details` column:

```py
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'asOfDate' : ['2022-06-06'], 'name' : ['Vasanth'], 'details': ['{"degree":"BE", "score":72.0, \r\n"subject" :"ECE"}'] })

df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['details'].apply(json.loads).tolist())).drop('details',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     asOfDate     name degree  score subject
0  2022-06-06  Vasanth     BE   72.0     ECE
```

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1586944/git/risk-etl/script/mars/test.py", line 67, in <module>
    df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['details'].apply(json.loads).tolist())).drop('details', axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\1586944\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3591, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2217, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
ValueError: Trailing data

Comment: It looks like some of your JSON values are invalid, or perhaps they have newlines in them.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1586944/git/risk-etl/script/mars/test.py", line 67, in <module>
    df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['details'].apply(json.loads).tolist())).drop('details', axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\1586944\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3591, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2217, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
ValueError: Trailing data

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data which demonstrates this problem, then I'm sure we can solve it

Comment: Hi @Nick i have used the data from the question only..Another question, is import pd.json as json  different from import json

Comment: @Vasanth If you see my answer I have only used the data from your question too. I don't know if `pd.json` is the same as `json`, you should try just `import json` instead...

Answer (score 0):

I think you received the error because the data in the details column is still a `sting` not a `json/dict` object.

Here we print the type of the first element in the `details` column

```py
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
print(type(df['details'][0]))
```

```py
<class 'str'>
```

1. So you can simply convert it to `json/dict` object as **Nick** suggested

```py
df['details'] = df['details'].apply(json.loads)
print(type(df['details'][0]))
```

```py
<class 'dict'>
```

2. Use `json_normalize` to convert the `json` objects to `DataFrame`

```py
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['details'])
print(df2)
```

```
  degree  score subject
0     BE   72.0     ECE
1     BE   72.0     ECE
```

3. we join the 2 dataframes and remove the `details` column

```py
df = df.join(df2).drop('details', axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
     asOfDate     name degree  score subject
0  2022-06-06  Vasanth     BE   72.0     ECE
1  2022-06-06  Vasanth     BE   72.0     ECE
```

---

finally all in one line

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['details'].apply(json.loads))).drop('details', axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
     asOfDate     name degree  score subject
0  2022-06-06  Vasanth     BE   72.0     ECE
1  2022-06-06  Vasanth     BE   72.0     ECE
```

Comment: Getting this error when executing this method: df2 = json.json_normalize(df['details']) File "C:\Users\1586944\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 228, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'Getting this error when executing this method: df2 = json.json_normalize(df['details']) File "C:\Users\\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 228, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Getting this error when executing this method: df2 = json.json_normalize(df['details']) File "C:\Users\1586944\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 228, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'Getting this error when executing this method: df2 = json.json_normalize(df['details']) File "C:\Users\\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 228, in itervalues
    return iter(obj.values(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'